# Spark job not ending : Show of dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have to merge 5 dataframes into a single dataframe. The dataframes look like,

```
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Timestamp          |sentence                                                                   |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020-03-13 12:01:32| : 0792b8d1-7ad9-43fc-9e75-9b1f2612834c updated field1 with beats|
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Timestamp          |sentence                                                                |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020-03-04 23:10:59| : 0792b8d1-7ad9-43fc-9e75-9b1f2612834c updated field2 with kobo |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Timestamp          |sentence                                                                |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020-03-13 12:01:32| : 0792b8d1-7ad9-43fc-9e75-9b1f2612834c updated field3 with beats|
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Timestamp          |sentence                                                           |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020-02-20 07:20:29| : 0792b8d1-7ad9-43fc-9e75-9b1f2612834c added an field4 with beats|
+-------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|Timestamp          |sentence                                                       |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|2020-02-20 07:20:29| : 0792b8d1-7ad9-43fc-9e75-9b1f2612834c added a field5 with beats|
+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Show works fine when union is applied for the first 3 dataframes, but upon including the last two, the spark job is not progressing.

To do the union I used,

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4, df5]
df_final = reduce(lambda a, b: a.union(b), dfs)
df_final.show()
```

I want to display the result, but the job is stuck at `showString at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:0`

How do I go about this issue?

Comment: Are they large dataframes?

Comment: No they are pretty small, they include mostly 10 rows each at the max.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine for me, as you have same datatype for `union`  as well as same column names for `unionByName`

I think this is not the issue with `union` or `unionByName` There might be some other issue. Might be resource crunch from the scheduler stand point. See any other jobs are running parllely.

Comment: Tried restarting spark, and the job was completed, now it's stuck at the show operation. Any suggestions regarding this, please let me know. Thanks a lot !